# Multiple Categorical values for a single feature how to convert them to binary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data set of movies which has 28 columns. One of them is genres. For each row in this data set, the value for column genres is of the form "Action|Animation|Comedy|Family|Fantasy".
 I want to encode them using pandas.get_dummies() but since the columns have multiple values, how to deal with such conditions?

I have attached the sample data but with only the relevant columns [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4lsS.png).
I am expecting an output as [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYs1U.png).

But when I use below code to convert categorical values to binary,

```
import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
DataConverted = pd.get_dummies(Data)
DataConverted.to_csv('sample_out.csv')
```

The output is as shown below(I'm not able to post more than two images):

```
movie_title_Avatar ,movie_title_Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ,movie_title_Spectre ,genres_Action|Adventure|Fantasy,genres_Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi,genres_Action|Adventure|Thriller
1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
```

Comment: The original question with a much better answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14847/multiple-categorical-values-for-a-single-feature-how-to-convert-them-to-binary-u

Answer (score -1):

This one here is a little tricky, but I can assure there isn't many genre types. So you could make constants with values of the form 2^n. For example, Action genre will have the constant value 1; Adventure type might be 2; and Fantasy 4. Then, you can save the genre performing an 'or' operation with the constant values. For example, if Avatar genre is Action and Fantasy but not Adventure. You will save it like this

```
  const int ACTION = 1, ADVENTURE = 2, FANTASY = 4;
  movie.genre = movie.genre | ACTION | FANTASY
```

Then, when you read the value of the column gender, you will have to perform an 'and' operation with each constant value. For example, to know if Avatar's genre is Action you you just have to do the following and see if it is Adventure:

```
    if(movie.genre & ACTION == ACTION)
         print("Action movie") //will execute
    if(movie.genre & ADVENTURE == ADVENTURE)
         print("Adventure movie") //won't execute
```

Now, with decimal values it might not make sense to you. But you must think about this with binary values; 1 is 0001; 2 = 0010 and 4 = 0100. Performing the 'or' operation in the Avatar example will lead you to make genre equal to 01001. Which is 5 in decimal enumeration system. But 01001 isn't actually a genre type. So, to know if a movie is a specific genre type, you must perform an 'and' operation with the constant values. Therefore, performing movie.genre & ACTION is equivalent to 01001 & 00001 = 00001. Now, the value 00001 is the same constant value interpreted as ACTION. This means, Avatar is an Action movie but not an Adventure movie because 01001 & 00010 is equals to zero, not equals to the constant value of ADVENTURE (2).